# I am getting ValueError of invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
  urlpatterns = [
url(r'^all/$','article.views.articles'),
url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>)\d+/','article.views.article'),
  ]
```

That is my urls.py and,

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from article.models import Article
def articles(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html',{'articles':Article.objects.all()})

def article(request, article_id=1):
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article':Article.objects.get(id=article_id)})
```

Above is my views.py but when i try to run mysite/get/1/ it gives me error of invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''. I have tried solving it by referring other questions, but it still does not work.

Comment: Could you include the traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the syntax for named captures. Here is how they are in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)

```
(?P<name>pattern)
```

So you should make your pattern

```
(?P<article_id>\d+)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in my regular expression.

Comment: There's no need to convert to an int, it works perfectly well with a string. The problem, as OP says, was that the regex wasn't capturing the ID at all.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that would be okay.